# Python, script to input a string and get the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm building a script to input a taiwanese address ('928屏東縣東港鎮嘉新路160、162號') into this website `URL = "https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html"` and get the latitude and logitude as output.

I tried some htlm readers like beautiful soap or selenium but without success, probably I am missing something. Can anybody suggest me what I need to fix to print the output in python?

```py
import urllib, os, urllib.request, time,  requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import re

URL = "https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html"
PropertyAddress_CN = "928屏東縣東港鎮嘉新路160、162號"

input_address = {"Type address here to get lat long":PropertyAddress_CN}

r = requests.post(URL, data = input_address)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

result = soup.find_all()

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

The website uses an API end, to which you can post directly:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.latlong.net/_spm4.php"
r = requests.post(
    url,
    data={"c1": "928屏東縣東港鎮嘉新路160、162號", "action": "gpcm", "cp": ""},
    headers={"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"},
)
if r.status_code == 200:
    lat, long = r.text.split(",")
    print("Latitude {}, Longitude {}".format(lat, long))
```

Please make sure you comply with the terms and conditions of the webservice.

Comment: Thanks Simon, it works perfectly, didn't know about the API end.